# (SUMO) TraaS Dynamic Routing & Incomplete Routes

Tags: java, dynamic, routes, simulation, sumo

I'm unsure on how to dynamically assign routes to vehicles (with each vehicle having a route which is unique to them) depending on certain conditions (i.e. traffic jams, congestion). I'm using TraaS to interface with SUMO and need to react to certain conditions and dynamically assign routes to particular vehicles depending on their location relative to the road condition.

I've read about automatic re-routing here: http://sumo.dlr.de/wiki/Demand/Automatic_Routing, however I'm unsure how to activate this (if it's not done by default), or if this is even the correct solution.

So far I've been able to assign a route in TraaS, but I can't seem to use DUAROUTER during runtime to be able to generate the route from point A to C without defining the intermediate edges, C (trip -> route). From my understanding a trip is a start and end destination, whereas a route is this with the addition of all of the intermediate edges passed through.

```
        SumoStringList listExample = new SumoStringList();
        ArrayList<String> edgeList = new ArrayList<>();

        edgeList.add("edge1");
        edgeList.add("edge3");
        listExample.addAll(edgeList);

        conn.do_job_set(Route.add("test", listExample));
```

When ran (without `edge2` being included in the `edgeList`) I get the error `Vehicle 'testVehicle' has no valid route. No connection between edge 'edge1' and edge 'edge3'.`, which is resolved upon including `edge2`.

Is it possible to convert trips -> routes during runtime? 
Is there a way to call DUAROUTER (or another tool) during runtime in TraaS?

Many thanks

Comment: Also, is there any sort of method present in Traci/TraaS which returns a list of the returned edges if an edge is passed to it? I say this so I can manually build the route the vehicle shall take (for example, to move around the congestion in a particular way).

Comment: This has been answered here: https://www.mail-archive.com/sumo-user@eclipse.org/msg00859.html